# Permalink structure in a custom post type

Tags: wordpress

Please help.

There is a custom post type "**films**" and a taxonomy "**genres**" with the following structure of permalinks:

**http://example.com/films/film-1/

http://example.com/genres/genre-1/**

To address **http://example.com/genres/** get the **404 error**.

I want need to type links **http://example.com/films/genres/genre-1/** and the list of movies posts at **http://example.com/films/genres/**.

Thank you in advance for your help.

My code:

```html
function films_catalog() {
 $labels = array(
  'name' => 'Films catalog',
  'singular_name' => 'Film', 
  'add_new' => 'Add film',
  'add_new_item' => 'Add new film',
  'edit_item' => 'Edit film',
  'new_item' => 'New film',
  'all_items' => 'All films',
  'view_item' => 'Show films',
  'search_items' => 'Search films',
  'not_found' =>  'No films.',
  'not_found_in_trash' => 'No films.',
  'menu_name' => 'Films' 
 );
 $args = array(
  'labels' => $labels,
  'public' => true,
  'show_ui' => true,
  'has_archive' => true,
  'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/img/films_icon.png', 
  'menu_position' => 20, 
  'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'author', 'thumbnail'),
 );
 register_post_type('films', $args);
}
add_action( 'init', 'films_catalog' );


function create_films_taxonomies(){
 $labels = array(
  'name' => 'Genres',
  'singular_name' => 'Genres',
  'search_items' =>  'Search genres',
  'popular_items' => 'Popular genres',
  'all_items' => 'All genres',
  'parent_item' => null,
  'parent_item_colon' => null,
  'edit_item' => 'Edit genre',
  'update_item' => 'Update genre',
  'add_new_item' => 'Add new genre',
  'new_item_name' => 'New genre name',
  'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Genres list',
  'add_or_remove_items' => 'Add or remove genres',
  'choose_from_most_used' => 'Popular genres',
  'menu_name' => 'Genres',
 );

 register_taxonomy('genres', array('films'), array(
  'hierarchical' => false,
  'labels' => $labels,
  'show_ui' => true,
  'query_var' => true,
  'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'genres' ),
 ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_films_taxonomies', 0 );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function films_catalog() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Films catalog',
        'singular_name' => 'Film', 
        'add_new' => 'Add film',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add new film',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit film',
        'new_item' => 'New film',
        'all_items' => 'All films',
        'view_item' => 'Show films',
        'search_items' => 'Search films',
        'not_found' =>  'No films.',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No films.',
        'menu_name' => 'Films' 
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/img/films_icon.png', 
        'menu_position' => 20, 
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'author', 'thumbnail'),
    );
    register_post_type('films', $args);
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'films_catalog' );


function create_films_taxonomies(){
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Genres',
        'singular_name' => 'Genres',
        'search_items' =>  'Search genres',
        'popular_items' => 'Popular genres',
        'all_items' => 'All genres',
        'parent_item' => null,
        'parent_item_colon' => null,
        'edit_item' => 'Edit genre',
        'update_item' => 'Update genre',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add new genre',
        'new_item_name' => 'New genre name',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Genres list',
        'add_or_remove_items' => 'Add or remove genres',
        'choose_from_most_used' => 'Popular genres',
        'menu_name' => 'Genres',
    );

    register_taxonomy('genres', array('films'), array(
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'genres' ),
    ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_films_taxonomies', 0 );
```

this works fine all the way copy and paste in for file

Answer (score 0):

add this line

```
flush_rewrite_rules( false );
```

after

```
register_post_type('films', $args);
```

if not solve this please go to settings permalink first save to custom and run then change it to post-type.

Hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: Nothing changes.